# Templates failing when navigating to them

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on creating a website.  This is a very basic issue.  When I click on different routes from the homepage I get a 404 error.  I just don't see what is wrong with the code this early in the game.

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/app/templates/home.html'
        });
    $routeProvider.when('/content', {
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/contact.html'
        });
    $routeProvider.when('/aboutme', {
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/aboutme.html'
        });
    $routeProvider.when('/portfolio', {
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/portfolio.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
           templateUrl: '/'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
      <nav ng-controller="NavCtrl">
        <li ng-model="navigation" ng-repeat="navigation in navigation"><a href="{{navigation.link}}">{{navigation.name}}</a></li>
      </nav>
  <ng-view></ng-view>

  <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/controllers/navigation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my only controller...

```
angular.module('app').controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.navigation = [
        {name: 'Home', link: '/'},
        {name: 'Portfolio', link: '/portfolio'},
        {name: 'About Me', link: '/aboutme'},
        {name: 'Contact Me', link: '/contact'}
    ];
}]);
```

error message...

[image]

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon K pointed out that I needed `<base href="/">` tag added to my `<head>`.  This still wasn't producing the correct output I was looking for.  But when I added `<base href="{{navigation.link}}">` to the `<head>` everything started working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Idk how your folders are structured but chances are your `templateUrl`s are pointing to the wrong place.

It's very likely that you don't require `/app/`

Try just `templates/contact.html`

Side note: you have `.when('/content',` as one of your routes instead of `.when('/contact',`

Comment: I added a picture of my folder structure, maybe that will help?  I removed 'app' from where the template was pointing but that didn't help.

Comment: From you image, it appears your routes were correct to begin with.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything else wrong with your code (except that your `otherwise` route is using `templateUrl: '/'` instead of `redirectTo: '/'`)

Comment: I also noticed an error message on the home page.  Not sure if it has anything to do with this.  I added a pic of the error as well.

Comment: You have to add a `<base href="/">` tag to your `<head>` when using HTML5 mode

Comment: I added that but now the page isn't displaying all of the navigation options listed out through ng-repeat.  It just says {{navigation.name}}?

Comment: Okay I think I have it figured out now.  I added `<base href="{{navigation.link}}">` to my `<head>`.  That seemed to work.  Thanks for all your input.